# Angular - Combine two input ng-model into one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular, please help me. I have two input fields, one with area code and other with the number.

```
// First input field for area code
<input area-input type="tel" required="true" name="area" 
ng-model="employee.home.area"></input>

// Second input field for number
<input phone-input type="tel" required="true"
name="number" ng-model="employee.home.number"></input>
```

I want to combine them into one like area code + number.

Thanks in advance. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot have just one input field?

Comment: If I have one input field then how can i display both parts of numbers. @RaniRadcliff. It is done by some one else and i am trying to fix it

Comment: It's a little unclear what it is your looking for - here is a jsfiddle with a few options:

[https://jsfiddle.net/np1vyx99/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/np1vyx99/1/)

Comment: are you have another fields in `employee.home` fields? or only _number_ and _area_?

Comment: Thanks @Kyle It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom directive, and use [`parsers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) and [`formatters`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) from [`ngModelControllers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

So you can get something like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.employee = {home : {area:'area', number:'number'}};
  })
  .directive('phone', function() {
    function formatPhone(value) {
      console.log('format',value);
          if (!value) return;
          if (!value.number) return value.area;
          value.area = value.area||'';
          return value.area + "-" + value.number;
        }
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope:{
        ngModel:'='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(function(){return scope.ngModel;},function(n){
          if(!n) scope.ngModel={area:"",number:""}
          console.log('watch',n);
          ngModel.$viewValue= formatPhone(n);
          ngModel.$render();
        },true);
        
        ngModel.$formatters.push(formatPhone);
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          console.log(value, value.split('-'));
          var parts = value.split('-');
          return {
            area: parts[0],
            number: parts[1]||''
          };
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    // First input field for area code<br/>
    <input area-input="" type="tel" required="true" name="area" ng-model="employee.home.area" /> 
    <br/>// Second input field for number<br/>
    <input phone-input="" type="tel" required="true" name="number" ng-model="employee.home.number" />
    <br/><br/>
    //custom field. format: area-number<br/>
  <input data-phone type="tel" required="true" ng-model="employee.home" />
  {{employee}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Grundy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{employee.home.area}}+{{employee.home.number}}` in your html on

```
use `employee.home.area+employee.home.number` in your `controller`
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But its editable field and I want something like 
<input phone-input type="tel" required="true"
name="number" ng-model="employee.home.number" + ng-model="employee.home.area">

I know, i can't have two ng-model on it, but this is just to show you ,this is what I want to achieve

Comment: Define a variable like `areaTel` in your controller and bind it to on input element, then separated `Area` and `Tel` within your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Mike Anderson